# How many proteins are synthesized in human body throughout life?

Tags: human-biology, homework, development

My idea to calculate this is:

1. Define up to what age will do the calculation. (for instance 60)
2. Determine how many cells born and died up to that point in life. (by type of cell)
3. Determine how many proteins are synthesized in the cells life. (by type of cell)

Points 2 and 3 are not constant throughout the life of the human body. To calculate this data I need a function.

After obtaining all the data: complete calculations of addition and multiplication.

The question is not about mathematics, but about useful data to make these calculations. Another approach would be welcome too.

Comment: Related [question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/3327/9099).

Comment: Also related, [protein turnover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_turnover).

Comment: you will probably want to take a mean lifetime of human cells - some of them are very slow growing and life practically forever, others relatively short - just a few days.  (blood cells and male gametes for instance).  the amount of protein synthesis would also similarly vary.  a single cell type with good measurements would be good to see..

Comment: Just to add another factor, there are many proteins that are often recycled and persist for quite some time.  I would be impressed to see some solid arguments on this.  I think you might have some luck by trying to break down to average masses of the various tissues, but I believe this will be quite a challenge.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe measuring mRNA content can help to estimate the speed of protein construction. It is a hard question btw...