# What percentage of human body's cells are contained in blood?

Tags: human-biology

What percentage of human body's cells are contained in blood vs. the rest of the body?

Comment: The background of the question was a (somewhat silly) theoretical question of "[how much of your body's cells can you replace with blood transfusion](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/49594/976)". I realize that the exact biological answers to the two questions will be different, but I think it's a good first approximation.

Comment: You should probably edit the question to contain that background then.

Comment: When you mean "percentage", do you mean my type or by mass?

Comment: @anon by cell count

Comment: According to [this answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/20833/17041), there are 2.63 × 10^13 red blood cells, which is **70.69%** of the 3.72 × 10^13 total human cells in the estimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The human body has about $3.72 × 10^{13}$ cells according to [Bianconi et al. 2013](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23829164), although this [is disputed](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/how-many-human-cells-are-there-in-our-body-on-average).

It also has about 5 liters of blood, which is made approximately 40-45% of erythrocytes. Let's assume 2.5 liters = 2500 $cm^3$ of red blood cells (RBC). Assuming a mean value of 5 millions RBC per $mm^3$ there should be in total $5 \cdot 10^6 \cdot 10^3 \cdot 2500 = 7.5 \cdot 10^{12}$ RBC.

By completely taking out white blood cells and thrombocytes out of the equation, a number of ${7.5 \over {3.72 \cdot 10}} \cdot 100 = 20 \%$ of **number of cells** are contained in the blood (approximately).

Answer (score 1):

Given the hypothetical 70 kg man, let him be separated into components:

**Blood**: 7% (70 kg x .07 = 4.9 kg)

Of that, 60% is plasma, so (4.9 kg x .4 = 1.96 kg blood cell weight.)

Therefore of a 70 kg male, ~ 2 kg is blood cells

**Tissue and bone**: 93% of body weight (70 kg x .93 = 65kg)

Of that, 27% is extracellular fluid, so (65 kg x .73 = ~ 47.5 kg cell weight)

But we need to subtract the weight of bones:

Dry bone weight = ~6.5% total body weight, (70 kg x .065 = 4.55 kg bone weight)

So, cell weight minus extracellular fluid:

Blood cells: 2 kg
Body cells (minus bone weight): 43 kg

**2kg/(43kg + 2 kg) = 4.4% of the weight of cells in the body are the blood cells.**

Comment: Isn't a human being about 75% other organisms though? As in, of that 70kg, about 50kg doesn't actually have the human's DNA?